# overwrite file only at the first actual write

Tags: c++, fstream

I would like to open a file for writing, such that the file is wiped and written over at the first write instruction. That is, the file should retain its contents when opened, and only at the first insertion is actually written over.

Using `std::fstream`, if I use the mode `std::ios_base::out`, the file is immediately wiped as soon as the constructor is called

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream f("test.txt", std::ios_base::out);
    // Now test.txt is empty
    f << "hello";
}
```

This behavior would be ok if test.txt does not exists. But if test.txt exists, I would like to have its contents preserved until I write to it. If I open it with

```
std::fstream f("test.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in);
```

indeed an existing file is still preserved, and it is written over only on `f << "hello"`.
However, if the file exists and contains more data then the string "hello", then `f << "hello"` will only overwrite the first 5 characters. I would like the file to be wiped, as if it were opened with `std::ios_base::out`, but only when I execute `f << "hello"`.

**Context**

The problem arises with a routine like this:

```
 void do_something(std::ostream& s)
 {
      //... very long computation
      s << "some infos" << std::endl;
 }
```

I call `do_something` passing to it a stream, which could or could not be a file. If it is a file, I would like to be able to inspect test.txt before the computation is done.

One possibility could be to wrap a `fstream` in a new object that actually opens the file only when `operator<<` is called, something like

```
 #include <fstream>

 class myfstream {
    std::fstream m_f;
    std::string m_filename;
 public:
    myfstream(std::string& filename) : m_filename{filename} { }
    template <typename U>
    myfstream& operator<<(const U& s) { if (!m_f.is_open()) m_f.open(m_filename, std::ios_base::out); m_f << s; return *this; }
 };
```

The drawback of this solution is the lack of flexibility: if the routine `do_something` does something else than just calling `operator<<`, one has to define all the other members of `std::ostream`, to mimick its behavior. Also, to retain flexibility `do_something` has to be declared as

```
 template <typename S>
 void do_something(S& o);
```

Is there a better solution? Would it be possible, say, given a `fstream` to delete all data *after* the current position of the output indicator?

**Update**

Apparently, a possible solution is to get the actual write position with `tellp()` and after closing the file, resize it. See following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  typename std::fstream::pos_type size;
  {
    char d;
    std::fstream f("test.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    std::cin >> d; // Just to pause
    f << "hello";
    size = f.tellp();
  }

  char d;
  std::cin >> d; // Just to pause
  std::filesystem::resize_file("test.txt", size);
  return 0;
}
```

(The `std::cin` are there only to pause and be able to check the actual contents of the file).
Testing the program, after the first "pause" the file is still intact. After the second pause, the first characters have been overwritten with the string "hello", but any text following that is still untouched. Finally, `resize_file` shrinks the file to the actual length of the written string.

The above code does an implicit conversion between a `pos_type` as returned from `tellp()` and a `std::uintmax_t` as required from [`resize_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file).

Is this conversion safe?

Comment: you can open a different file and only when closing write to the actual one

Comment: the typical approach used by many applications is to write to a different file, and then, once complete, use a `std::rename` to overwrite the old file with the new one (that might need a remove first depending on your platform).

Comment: I'd say the most common approach is to close and reopen the stream with the truncation option set, just before you call `operator<<`.